# How to sum a column from a running total data table in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sum, calculated-columns

I am currently working on a project and am running into an error that says: `Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier`. I have a column named "Total#" in a BusinessAnalytics data table. I want to sum the column together so that I can use it to calculate a percentage of members and percentage of nonmembers. How can I fix this?

My code for a data table with running totals

```
        Dim decTotalNumber As Decimal
        Dim decPercentSales As Decimal
        Dim intRow As Integer

        If chkRewards.Checked = True Then
            intRow = 1 'member
        Else
            intRow = 0 'nonmember
        End If

        With BusinessAnalytics.Rows(intRow)

            .Item("Total#") += 1

            decTotalNumber = BusinessAnalytics.Compute("SUM(Total#)", Nothing)
            decPercentSales = Convert.ToDecimal(.Item("Total#")) / decTotalNumber

            .Item("%Total") = decPercentSales.ToString("P1")

        End With


        GridView3.DataSource = BusinessAnalytics
        GridView3.DataBind()
```

Comment: I assume the error is coming from the BusinessAnalytics.Compute Method call?  Are you able to show us what this method does or is it a 3rd party library?  If 3rd party library, are you able to share which one it is?  Is having a column called _**Total#**_ causing an issue with the aggregate method?  It's a little strange seeing a column name with a **#** on the end of the name.  Just a few of the questions that came to mind while reading your question

Comment: The error is definitely from the BusinessAnalytics.Compute Method call. I'm learning this from a college course and there was not much explanation on how to compute the sum of a column on a data table. We have never talked about 3rd party libraries so I am not quite sure. Our professor has used Total# in the past for column names and data tables always work, I don't know if that would affect the .compute function or not.

Comment: @NickScotney DataTable.Compute() is a method on DataTable objects (which I assume BusinessAnalytics is)  On the actual question, do agree '#' or '%' in a column name probably not the best but that aside don't think this code is actually going to do what you expect, appreciate the use of 'With' but wonder if you might be confusing it with a loop.  As is you're only updating the Total# on one line potential leaving null values your compute expression is tripping on.  Personally, I prefer doing this sort of thin via Linq expressions, seem more robust to me

Answer (score 0):

Your column name contains non-alphanumeric characters, so it should be wrapped in square brackets or "`" (grave accent) quotes.

[Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-7.0)

So your statement should be:

```
decTotalNumber = BusinessAnalytics.Compute("SUM([Total#])", Nothing)
```